# Codemirror code displays only after click in Angular

Tags: angularjs, codemirror

I have a modal that needs to display some code using codemirror and I am developing the app in AngularJS. The html looks like the following:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div ui-codemirror="{onLoad:codemirrorLoaded}" ui-codemirror-opts="viewEventEditorOptions" data-ng-model="event.text"></div>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is that the code displays in the div only after I click inside it. I have tried refreshing the editor using an event like the following but it is not working:

```
$scope.codemirrorLoaded = function(_editor){
    // Events
    _editor.on("beforeChange", function(){ _editor.refresh() });
    _editor.on("change", function(){ _editor.refresh() });
};
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about codemirror but is it possible onLoad is called before your view is instanciated? If you have a break-point in your codemirrorLoaded callback, does it reach it before first click?

Comment: It's getting called before the modal is displayed. Doesn't get called again when I do the first click.

Comment: maybe try to trigger that event manually, from your JS code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out the moment at which the editor becomes visible (it is apparently not visible when initialized), and at *that* point call its `refresh` method.

Answer (score 1):

Add onload action to your options and refresh the codemirror after some milliseconds. Ex :

```
modalScope.editorOptions = {
    lineWrapping : true,
    lineNumbers: true,
    readOnly: 'nocursor',
    mode: 'yaml',
    onLoad: function(_editor){
        modalScope.editor = _editor;

        // Load without click
        setTimeout(function(){
            modalScope.editor.refresh();
        }, 100);
    }
  };
```

Comment: In the case the codemirror is added to the hidden dom element, you can use the addon autorefresh to make the codemirro visible at the first time it becomes visible. http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_autorefresh

Answer (score 0):

There was a directive called ui-refresh described on [ui-refresh-directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror#ui-refresh-directive) so the following code worked. Thanks for the comments!

```
<div ui-codemirror="{onLoad:codemirrorLoaded}" ui-refresh="true" ui-codemirror-opts="viewEventEditorOptions" data-ng-model="event.text"></div>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you do anything else but adding the `ui-refresh` directive?

Answer (score 0):

I use ui-refresh="true", but it only show after click to it.

```
<div ui-refesh="true" ui-codemirror-opts="jsonEditorOption" data-ng-model="user.UserJsonDataParse"></div>
```

Comment: that doesn't work because `true` never changes, there needs to be a scope variable that changes when that DOM part becomes visible

Answer (score 0):

There is an display addon called autorefresh 
https://codemirror.net/addon/display/autorefresh.js
include it in your scripts and use one of the fallowing options.

Option 1 HTML

```
<div ui-codemirror="{onLoad:codemirrorLoaded}"</div>
```

Option 1 TypeScript

```
codemirrorLoaded(_editor) {
        // Editor part
        var _doc = _editor.getDoc();
        _editor.focus();
        // Options
        _editor.setOption('autoRefresh', true);
        }
```

Option 2 HTML

```
<div ui-codemirror="{autoRefresh:true}">
```

Option 3 HTML

```
<div ui-codemirror ui-codemirror-opts="editorOptions">
```

Option 3 TypeScript

```
editorOptions{
              autoRefresh:true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used a simple function to show the editor and change from true to false

```
// HTML

<div ng-show="editorEnabled">
    <ui-codemirror ui-refresh="editorEnabled" ng-model="function"></ui-codemirror>
</div

// JS

$scope.editorEnabled= false;

$scope.enableEditor= function() {
    $scope.editorEnabled= true;
}
```